# Compare more than one column in different sheet and remove

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a problem - I have 2 tables.

First table :

```
Number | Factur | Items 
45001    18001      A
45001    18001      B
45001    18001      C
45002    18002      Z
45002    18002      A
```

Second Table :

```
Number | Factur | Items 
45001    18001      A
45002    18002      A
```

First table is my real data, and second table is my filter, so I want to match data between first table and second table with 3 parameter, if data match it will remove automatically

The result should be like this :

```
Number | Factur | Items 
45001    18001      B
45001    18001      C
45002    18002      Z
```

hope someone can help me me

Thanks in advance, cheers!!

Comment: Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Find below a screenshot of the formula i have applied

You can filter in column E on found and not found to get your desired output

[image]

I have created two additional columns, one for code and one for filtering

formula for code is simile concatenation of all three columns
in cell A3 it is `=B3&C3&D3`

and in cell A12 it is `=B12&C12&D12`

formula in cell E3 is simple vlookup with an if.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A3,$A$12:$A$13,1,0)),"not found","found")
```